# Convert an array of arrays to an array of objects with mapped properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What is the best way of converting an array of arrays to objects so that the indices are replaced with given mapping properties.

For example:

```
let cars = [
    [1, "Honda", "Honda description here"],
    [2, "Mercedes", "Mercedes description here"],
    [3, "Toyota", "Toyota description here"],
];

let mapping = {
    0: 'id',
    1: 'name',
    2: 'description',
};
```

So the final result is:

```
[
    {id: 1, name: 'Honda', description: 'Honda description here'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Mercedes', description: 'Mercedes description here'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Toyota', description: 'Toyota description here'},
];
```

Comment: Hint: The code should use nested loops.

Comment: The outer loop is over the cars, the inner loop is over the mappings. The inner loop adds properties to the object, the outer loop pushes the properties onto the result array. You can use the `.map()` function for the outer loop.

Comment: I suggest that you look at the `map()` function of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `map` command. Note: this code assumes there are mappings for each element of the array.

```js
let cars = [
    [1, "Honda", "Honda description here"],
    [2, "Mercedes", "Mercedes description here"],
    [3, "Toyota", "Toyota description here"],
];

let mapping = {
    0: 'id',
    1: 'name',
    2: 'description',
};

let result = cars.map(a => {
  let obj = {};
  a.forEach((v,i) => {
    obj[mapping[i]] = v;
  });
  return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the merged result by using a combination of:

1. `[].map()` on the `cars` array to loop through its elements.
2. `[].reduce()` on each car element to reduce the three value into one object, taking advantage of the ordering you have in the `mapping` object.

Here is a solution that can be shortened into a one-liner:

```js
let cars = [
    [1, "Honda", "Honda description here"],
    [2, "Mercedes", "Mercedes description here"],
    [3, "Toyota", "Toyota description here"],
];
let mapping = {
    0: 'id',
    1: 'name',
    2: 'description',
};
let result = cars.map((car) => (
    car.reduce((acc, cur, i) => (
        Object.assign(acc, { [mapping[i]]: cur })
    ), {})
));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `acc[mapping[i]] = cur; return acc;` is uglier but avoids creating a new object in order to copy each property.

Comment: Incorrect, `Object.assign(acc, { [mapping[i]]: cur })` does not create a new object, `Object.assign({}, acc, { [mapping[i]]: cur })` does.

Comment: Right you are!  Cheers.